# this.$refs.canvas undefined in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I'm setting up a new project using `vuejs3` and `canvas`, but I'm trapped in `canvas` element. Could anyone give me some advice or ideas?

In my project I got `undefined` with `this.$refs.canvas`. Also when I use `document.getElementById('canvas')`, I get `null`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas
      ref="canvas"
      id="canvas"
      class="bg"
      width="400"
      height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    // const canvas = this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d') 
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    console.log(canvas)
  },
}
</script>
```

It will be appreciate if anyone can give me some help.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it in `mounted` method? The elements won't yet be rendered in `created`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements won't yet be rendered in `created`. Try `mounted`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas
      ref="canvas"
      id="canvas"
      class="bg"
      width="400"
      height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const canvas = this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d') 
    console.log(canvas)
  },
}
</script>
```

View the Lifecycle Diagram here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: @Veexyy don't worry, there's always still a lot to learn in this field ;)